# C: drive access permission in windows 7

Tags: windows, matlab, permissions, matlab-deployment

In matlab, I used a windows standalone application. There is a line in this application that writes a file in `C:\...\...\`. When I run the output exe file produced from this windows standalone application, the exe doesn't write in `C:\...\...\` neither tells me that there is a security issues in that partition. All the execution does is nothing. But, when I right-click and run the exe as administrator, it runs correctly.

I want to do it without right-click and run as administrator. Are there is a command in matlab that can do that?

Comment: because I want to .. are there a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a shortcut to your application, you can go to the Properties of the shortcut, click on Advanced in the Shortcut tab, and select "Run as administrator".  That way, whenever you start the application from the shortcut it will be run as an administrator.

(Disclaimer: applications really shouldn't "foul their own nest" by writing into Program Files.  This is bad design.)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Vista, unprivileged processes are not allowed to write to protected folders such as Program Files, because Program Files is designed to store code and not data. However, since this limitation has not been enforced in XP, MS has provided a backward-compatibility hack in the form of Virtual Store. Now, when a program tries to write to protected folder, its output is being redirected into a dedicated folder. This way, the program still "thinks" it writes to its usual location, while in fact it writes to an unprotected location. However, when you later check the Program Files location, you might not see the file - because it's not really there.

You can find more details here: [User Account Control Data Redirection](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx).

Comment: but I want to write in `C:\...\...\` .. I ave to .. do you have a solution?

Comment: @Omar, now that you've updated the question, I see it's not C's root. What's the actual path then? If you're trying to write to the programs folder, for instance, the file will actually be created in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`. Could this be the case?

Comment: here is the path I want to write in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v713\bin\k123198.mat`

Answer (score 1):

If you are administrator, add full control permission for your username to the destination folder. You do that by right clicking on the folder, going to properties and then security tab. Then edit and add you username with `Full Control` rights. Then you don;t have to run the the program as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can elevate a process once it is started, so Matlab cannot possibly have a command for that. Just running Matlab elevated.